# CFLAGS are ignored in Makefile

Tags: c++11, makefile

I am using the following makefile to build my project:

```
CC      = /usr/bin/g++
CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = 

OBJ = main.o pnmhandler.o pixmap.o color.o 

pnm: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o pnm $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

As I run make I get the following error:

> /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
>   with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

As I can read from the following line, the CFLAGS are not properly included, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong:

> g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp

Also tried `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`, without any results. Any ideas?

If I run `make -Bn`, I get:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o pnmhandler.o pnmhandler.cpp
g++    -c -o pixmap.o pixmap.cpp
g++    -c -o color.o color.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -o pnm main.o pnmhandler.o pixmap.o color.o
```

**EDIT:** Replacing the rule `%.o: %.c` with `%.o: %.cpp` fixes my problem.

Comment: Could you try calling make with `-Bn` once? (dry-run, rebuild-all)

Comment: Ok ... i resolved the problem. The rule `%.o: %.c` will of course never be called if I am working with C++ files. Sorry. And thanks for pointing me to `make -Bn`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you see

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

is that Make is invoking its standard rule to create the object file:

```
%.o: %.cpp
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

The command expands to

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<
```

---

Instead of setting `CC` and `CFLAGS` in your makefile, you should set `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`, which are meant for C++ rather than C.  That allows the built-in rule above to work for you, and then you just need to make sure the right linker is used, e.g. with

```
pnm: LINK.o=$(LINK.cc)
pnm: $(OBJ)
```

You also don't need the `%.o: %.c` rule, as you have no C sources.

---

Complete Makefile:

```
CXX      = /usr/bin/g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x 

OBJ = main.o pnmhandler.o pixmap.o color.o 

pnm: LINK.o=$(LINK.cc)
pnm: $(OBJ)

clean::
    $(RM) pnm

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: As you can read in the comments of my question, the error was related to an invalid rule. Your solution is wrong as the variables used could also be named HANNI and NANNI, cause they are explicitly used (`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<`).

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Accepted.